# Looking for a way to change width of wx.lib.masked.TimeCtrl instances (wxPython on windows)

Tags: python, wxpython

OK, here's the problem:

[image: Hour being blocked from viewing]

As you can see, when editing seconds in a `wx.lib.masked.TimeCtrl` instance, hours segment will be partially blocked. But width can not be changed with either `size` parameter or `SetSize` method, only height can be changed which won't solve the problem.

I've checked into the source code a little bit, and it looks like `TimeCtrl` is an inheritance of `BaseMaskedTextCtrl`, which is a multiple inheriance of `wx.TextCtrl` and `MaskedEditMixin`, and basically if `size` is given when creating a new `TimeCtrl` instance:

```
# allow for explicit size specification:
if size != wx.DefaultSize:
    # override (and remove) "autofit" autoformat code in standard time formats:
    maskededit_kwargs['formatcodes'] = 'T!'
```

But in fact `maskededit_kwargs['formatcodes'] = 'T!'` just tells `MaskedEditMixin` that: 1) it's a time format; 2) force all characters showing up to be uppercase according to these lines:

```
self._forceupper  = '!' in self._formatcodes
......
self._isTime     = 'T' in self._ctrl_constraints._formatcodes and _isTimeType(mask)
```

So basically the code that claims to allow for explicit size specification doesn't do anything about it, and I'm a little bit lost jumping around checking out which part in charge of changing width, anybody knows how to do it?

**P.S.: wxPython 3.0.2.0 on windows 7 64bit**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

There's actually a `SetFont` method in `BaseMaskedTextCtrl`:

```
def SetFont(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Set the font, then recalculate control size, if appropriate. """
        wx.TextCtrl.SetFont(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if self._autofit:
##            dbg('calculated size:', self._CalcSize())            
            self.SetClientSize(self._CalcSize())
            width = self.GetSize().width
            height = self.GetBestSize().height
##            dbg('setting client size to:', (width, height))
            self.SetInitialSize((width, height))
```

And as you can see `SetInitialSize` can be used for setting width and height.

It's quite convenient.